# using default consumer group of eventhub in azure data explorer in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-eventhub, azure-data-explorer

I can use `$Default` consumer group in connection azure data explorer cluster from the azure dashboard. but when I tried to do the same from the terraform, I am getting error.

#### Getting data of default consumer group

```
data "azurerm_eventhub_consumer_group" "default" {
  name                = "$Default"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.eh_namespace.name
  eventhub_name       = azurerm_eventhub.eh.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
}
```

#### Tried to use in adx

```
resource "azurerm_kusto_eventhub_data_connection" "eventhub_connection" {
  name                = var.adx_eh_connection_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.eh_adx.location
  cluster_name        = azurerm_kusto_cluster.adx.name
  database_name       = azurerm_kusto_database.database.name

  eventhub_id    = azurerm_eventhub.eh.id
  consumer_group = data.azurerm_eventhub_consumer_group.default.name

  table_name        = var.adx_db_table_name
  mapping_rule_name = var.ingestion_mapping_rule_name
  data_format       = var.eh_message_format
}
```

#### Getting error

```
Error: invalid value for consumer_group (The consumer group name can contain only letters,
numbers, periods (.), hyphens (-),and underscores (_), up to 50 characters, and 
it must begin and end with a letter or number.)
  on adx.tf line 25, in resource "azurerm_kusto_eventhub_data_connection" "eventhub_connection":
  25: resource "azurerm_kusto_eventhub_data_connection" "eventhub_connection" {
```

#### Versions

- Terraform: 0.14.6
- azurerm: 2.53.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was reported before in this **[Github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/7720)** but it has been resolved in `azurerm provider version 2.28.0`. For solution please use **latest terraform version and azurerm version**.

I tested the same with ***Terraform version 1.0.11*** and latest ***azurerm provider i.e. 2.88.1*** .

```
data "azurerm_eventhub_consumer_group" "consumer_group" {
  name                = "$Default"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.eventhub_ns.name
  eventhub_name       = azurerm_eventhub.eventhub.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_kusto_eventhub_data_connection" "eventhub_connection" {
  name                = "my-kusto-eventhub-data-connection"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  cluster_name        = azurerm_kusto_cluster.cluster.name
  database_name       = azurerm_kusto_database.database.name

  eventhub_id    = azurerm_eventhub.eventhub.id
  consumer_group = data.azurerm_eventhub_consumer_group.consumer_group.name
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I am using `azurerm` > 2.28.0. but when I tried with 2.88.1, it is working. Thanks

Comment: glad to be of help @PSKP :)